# "list indices must be integers, not float" / "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" error in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting this error while generating my dictionary. I have three lists. Following is the print

```
edge
[(6.0, 4.0), (4.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0), (3.0, 2.0), (5.0, 2.0), (5.0, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0)]
weight
[3, 5, 8, 0, 16, 2, 8]
node
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

My code

```
GraphDict = {}
for i in range(len(node)):
    print('node',node[i])
    GraphDict[node[i]] = []
    for k in range(len(edge)):
        if node[i] == edge[k][0]:
            GraphDict[node[i]][edge[k][1]] = weight[k]
            print('Edge: n1, n2: weights', GraphDict[node[i]])

print('Dictionary Print')           
print(GraphDict)
```

Error in line.
Error: list indices must be integers, not float

```
GraphDict[node[i]][edge[k][1]] = weight[k]
```

when i convert all floats into integer that are already in whole number then the error is "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

```
GraphDict = {}
for i in range(len(node)):
    print('node',node[i])
    GraphDict[node[i]] = []
    for k in range(len(edge)):
        if node[i] == edge[k][0]:
            print(int(node[i]))
            ni = int(node[i])
            print(int(edge[k][1]))
            ei = int(edge[k][1])
            print(weight[k])
            GraphDict[ni][ei] = weight[k]
            print('Edge: n1, n2: weights', GraphDict[node[i]])

print('Dictionary Print')           
print(GraphDict)
```

Comment: What do you not understand in `list indices must be integers, not float`?...

Comment: It is already an integer

Comment: No. Your list `node` contains float, and your list `edge` contains tuples of floats. As you can see, there is `.` within the number, so even `3.0` is considered as a float as long as it is not simply `3`.

Comment: I am not an expert but I think error is something else. As I convert it into integer it gives: "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Comment: LOL. I am done with losing my time here.

Comment: Thanks for the time. But can you let me know if i am asking the wrong question or am i totally messed up

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: "list indices must be integers, not float". So make sure to convert `node[i]` to `int` or store integers right at the very beginning:

```
GraphDict[int(node[i])]
```

or

```
node = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Same holds for `edge`.

Comment: Also If I add int() then it gives "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"